# "Login" for file retrieval

Tags: javascript, web

Say I have 30 graded exams that have been OCR graded and annotated in PDF form.

They are in the format of studentnumber.pdf (e.g. 111101.pdf).

How can I allow the students to retrieve it?

My first idea was to dump all the files into my website /~name/handback/ and then create a java script input box that asks for the student number x and then opens the corresponding x.pdf.

This is clearly not a good method however, since a student who knows another's ID can download their entire exam. How could I fix this? If I were to get each student to give me a password at the beginning of the term how could I store and use them?

Could anybody provide a minimal working example or a resource where I can learn how to do this?

Comment: For login always use server side scripting (like PHP), save user number and it's password in database.

Comment: Using a client-sided language isn't a secure way of doing this, it looks like you want to use the client to do something that you want to do over the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is easy to exploit, because in the JS source the path to the directory is visible. Someone could just enter the path to the folder and see a list of all files (if allowed by the webserver)

I would recommend a small php application with a database (sqlite perhaps) which prompts for a student id and a password and delivers the corrected exam on correct data. For all students who don't provide a password you could set a default password like their birthday. But check the privacy policy of your university / school and country if handing out exams like this is even allowed.

EDIT: For really small numbers, you can use arrays to store student id and password (only secure in PHP or other server-side solution)

Comment: Any chance you can tell me or send me a tutorial for how to set something like that up?

Comment: Depends on your server. If it allows use of php, we can do it. To check it, create a file `test.php` and put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into it. Upload this test file to the server and open it with your browser. If it shows info about your server, PHP is working, if it shows the text you put in the file, we had bad luck and it isn't working.

If I find time this day, I may create a working example.

Comment: I don't want to bother, but when you get some free time, would you be willing to do this for me?

Comment: @MathMajor I think this would be possible, but I can't check the availability of PHP on your server. But I will start to program it ;-)

Comment: @MathMajor Sorry for the delay, I just got it ready :) It isn't very fancy, but you don't need a database, all is set up in one file. My website host just cancelled my subscription, so I have to upload it to a foreign server. (eww) All important is said in the readme file.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/22unu7g12rsadcg/AACQsOioPGm2KWxuIafFUr-Za?dl=0

Comment: @MathMajor Thank you. It's nice when people appreciate my work. ;-) I will host it on a professional site.... after the exam time. I'm a student as well ^^

Comment: No problem. Are you studying computer science? I'm in my fourth year as a math major and will be heading off for a masters soon. In case you are curious, I am a TA and we are testing out the auto-multiple-choice package on LaTeX that automatically grades via OCR. The software annotates the exams with scores, etc. and I was trying to figure out a way to give the students their PDF's back. This was very helpful!

Comment: Yes I am. (University of Applied Sciences Kempten, Germany) I'm currently in 4. semester targeting a Bachelor of Science.

Some professors over here are trying to use a similar system for evaluation purposes but they are in the test phase too.